# Filtering search results with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails development and I've been adapting www.railstutorial.org's guide to learn the language. Here's my situation:

I have an index function that started off like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

This code shows all of the users in the database on the page. However, my users are members of teams (shown by a team_id column in Users) and I want a signed in user to only see their team members. So , using what I know and experimenting, I tried this:

```
def index
  @filter = User.all
  @users = @filter.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I was encouraged because the page continued to work just fine. However, as soon as I add any sort of actual query or method to @filter, I get the following error in the browser:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x00000001b18a90>
```

and it identifies the line

```
@users = @filter.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

as the problem. These search queries give me exactly what I'm after in the rails console, such as:

```
User.where(team_id: 1).take(50)
```

returns the results I'd expect. Also, if I remove @filter and change the code as follows:

```
def index
  @users = User.where(team_id: current_user.team_id).all
end
```

it works perfectly. 
 Why doesn't paginate have a problem when it's User. all, but it freaks out as soon as it's being handed less than the entire table?

(Edit: after some experimenting, I think that it's because will_paginate expects to be handed a table to go over and I've gotten the functionality I want it to have, but I figured someone else might answer the question, so I'm leaving it up. Also, any insight on why the code below works for will_paginate but the previous ones didn't would be appreciated).

Solution (includes a test to see if the user is an admin, who would need to be able to see all teams):

```
def index
 if @current_user.admin == true
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
 else
  @filter = User.where(team_id: current_user.team_id).all
  @users = @filter.paginate(page: params[:page])
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `User.all` rails converts it into an array of User objects. 
Try `User.all.class` and you will understand.

You can use `User.where(true)`. That should work and fetch all User records.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller add this line

```
  require 'will_paginate/array'
```

And then try again